# Help removing appended data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello I am using jquery to do some ajax that calls in some data from a database, on the mouseover and element the method runs and I get the expected results, however when I then mouse over another element, the method runs again, however I need to delete the first lot of data from the screen first, this is what I have so far,

```
$("a.contentlink").mouseover(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax ({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            success : function (html) {
                $('#abstract').append(html);
            }
        });
    });
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the [`empty`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/empty) method first, which removes all children from the matched elements.

For example:

```
$('#abstract').empty();
```

Alternatively, you can call the [`html`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val) function, which replaces the contents of the matched element with a string of HTML.

For example:

```
$('#abstract').html(html);
```